# Join two tables with time comparison

Tags: mysql, database-design, join

## Setting

I have two tables which I want to join.

**table1**

```
id, movement_time, coordinate_x, coordinate_y
123, 2014-06-08 08:01:24, 1, 10
123, 2014-06-08 08:01:54, 1, 11
321, 2014-06-08 08:01:30, 99, 2
...
```

**table2**

```
communication_time, from_id, to_id
2014-06-08 08:01:29, 123, 321
...
```

In both tables, the `time` columns are `DATETIME` type, so I can compare times.

Those two times may not be aligned. For example,  `user 123`'s movement time in `table1` may not appear in `table2`, as shown in the above sample, and vice versa.

## Problem

What I want to do is to join those two tables, such that

1) For each record in `table2`, I want to find the corresponding `coordinate_x` and `coordinate_y` for `from_id` and `to_id` respectively.

2) Since the two time columns don't align, chances are I can not find an exact time match. So I use the following rule:

```
- For each record in `table2`, I take its `time` and `from_id` (or `to_id`) as given, 

- Then, in `table1`, find the most recent record for the same `id`. The `movement_time` <= `communication_time`

- Attach the coordinates to the `table2` record
```

How to use MySQL to accomplish this task?

Thank you,

Pan

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by looking at just one case if 2014-06-08 08:01:29, 123:

```
SELECT t1.coordinate_x, t1.coordinate_y
    FROM table1 AS t1
    WHERE t1.movement_time <= '2014-06-08 08:01:29'
      AND t1.id = 123
    ORDER BY t1.movement_time DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

That would benefit from `INDEX(id, movement_time)`.

Does that correctly work for that one case?  Assuming it does, let's move on to actually use table2:

```
SELECT t2.communication_time,
       t1a.coordinate_x AS from_x,
       t1a.coordinate_y AS from_y
    FROM table2 AS t2
    JOIN (
        SELECT t1.coordinate_x, t1.coordinate_y
            FROM table1 AS t1
            WHERE t1.movement_time <= t2.communication_time
              AND t1.id = t2.from_id
            ORDER BY t1.movement_time DESC
            LIMIT 1;
         ) t1a;
```

Is it still working 'correctly'?

Shall I leave it as an "exercise to the reader" to also get the coordinates for `to_id`?  (Hint:  Another JOIN.)